# how to use isset inside addCondition in yii criteria

Tags: php, yii

Hi I've been trying to check if a field is existing using **isset** inside **addCondition** like this

```
$criteria->addCondition('isset(status_id)');
```

but no luck. Can anyone suggest the right syntax for this? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For checking a variable, you can use isset(). But what you are trying to do is not the correct way. The addCondition method is not supposed to execute PHP functions. Check the [documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria#addCondition-detail)

But If you want to check the value in `status_id`, tou can do like this -

```
$criteria->addCondition('status_id IS NOT NULL');
```

Answer (score 0):

check that your variable is set and it is in the correct form that you want, then add it in your condition.like:

```
if(isset($var) && preg_match($yourPattern , $var))
    $criteria->addCondition('status_id =' . $var );
```

if you use "compare" , it doesn't matter that it is set or not.

Answer (score 0):

try this:
if(isset(status_id))
{$criteria->addCondition('status_id');}