# IS NOT NULL not working in Yii Active Record

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I am trying something like this:

```
public function search() {

        $criteria = new CDbCriteria;

        $criteria->compare('user_details_id', $this->user_details_id);
        $criteria->compare('user_type_id', $this->user_type_id);
        $criteria->compare('customer_basics_id', $this->customer_basics_id);
        $criteria->compare('user_address_id', $this->user_address_id);
        $criteria->compare('user_city_id', $this->user_city_id);
        $criteria->compare('is_active', $this->is_active);
        $criteria->compare('create_dttm', $this->create_dttm, true);
        $criteria->compare('update_dttm', $this->update_dttm, true);

        // if condition is working
        if (isset($_GET['ulip'])) {
            $criteria->addCondition(
                    "customer_basics_id=" . CustomerBasics::getCustomerBasicsId(Yii::app()->session['user_id']), "AND"
            );
            $criteria->addCondition("user_city_id IS NULL");
        // else condition is working
        } else {
            $criteria->addCondition(
                    "customer_basics_id=" . CustomerBasics::getCustomerBasicsId(Yii::app()->session['user_id']), "AND"
            );
            $criteria->addCondition("user_city_id IS NOT NULL");
        }


    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria' => $criteria,
        'pagination' => array(
            'pageSize' => 10,
        ),
    ));
}
```

Here the issue is `if` condition is working fine and showing results according to the condition but else part is not working and it returns nothing. I think `IS NOT NULL` is not working here.

What is the issue ?

Comment: try `NOT ISNULL(user_city_id)`

Comment: @TheHumbleRat : its not working

Comment: Hmm, I can't see anything else and this post shows you have the correct syntax 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18954600/how-to-use-isset-inside-addcondition-in-yii-criteria
All I could possibly suggest is trying to put a static value like `$criteria->addCondition("user_city_id = 1");` or something similar to make sure it is working till that point.

Comment: Are you sure there are any data are returned with your condition (user_city_id IS NOT NULL) in DB?

Comment: @Ultimate did you figure this out, I would be interested to know the solution.

Comment: @TheHumbleRat: :( No I am still trying what is the issue. I'll post an answer whenever I fixed this. Thanks

Comment: @Ultimate I am available on the addresses shown on my profile. If I can help I will.

Comment: Can you show us the resulting SQL statement from logs? Also how `user_city_id` is defined?

Comment: @Ultimate any thoughts on the latest comments/answers?

Comment: Are you sure that `$_GET['ulip']` is not set, i.e. that the `else` part of the condition is followed?  You could `echo` some debug messages within each side of the `if` to be sure.  Simply having `?ulip=` or `&ulip=` in the querystring (even if nothing follows the `=`) will result in the variable being set, in which case you may also want to test its content e.g. `if (isset($_GET['ulip']) and $_GET['ulip'] != '')` or else ensure that the parameter is removed from the querystring.

Comment: Please dont use $_POST or $_GET in Active record classes this breaks MVC, if you care

Comment: @TheHumbleRat: Extremely Sorry for late reply. I've checked the answer of Hearaman and changed the code according to that, also cleared my old values from database and tried for new record and its working fine now. I think whatever Hearaman explained that is correct. BTW Thank you so much for your efforts in this.

Comment: Your very welcome. I was as interested in the answer as you. Glad it's fixed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**The Main reason.**

In your database table column(user_city_id),  you have **Empty values** not **NULL values**.
So your query is unable to operate "IS NULL" and "IS NOT NULL" on the corresponding column.

```
      1. NULL is Special Data Type.
      2. Where as Empty means a string/value which is empty.
```

You can read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5615747/what-is-the-difference-between-null-and-empty)

**No need to add operator for first addCondition**

For your information, When you are adding a condition to your criteria, no need to add "AND" operator becoz by default "AND" is the operator in [addConditon](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.14/framework/db/schema/CDbCriteria.php#L218). And no use if you add operation for first addCondition, You should add this for your next addConditions if you have any.

```
     //AND is not required here as AND is default operation. 
     //This operator (AND) wont help in first condition.
     $criteria->addCondition('condition1=1','AND');

     //This bellow condition will be concatenate with above condition so, here operator is required.
     $criteria->addCondition('condition2=1','OR');
```

**The Solution is**

I dont like to disturb default search method in my model.  **As i'm using MVC Framework, i should follow at least some MVC rules. Otherwise there is no meaning using this MVC.** So,  accessing $_GET stuff in my Model is not good here. so i'm creating a new method in my Model with two parameters.

```
        function yourModelMethod($isParamExist,$customer_basics_id)
        {
            $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
            $criteria->condition = "customer_basics_id=$customer_basics_id";        
            if($isParamExist)
            {            
                $criteria->condition='TRIM(user_city_id) =""';
            }
            else
            {
                $criteria->condition='TRIM(return_date) !=""';
            }

            return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
                'criteria' => $criteria,
            ));
        }
```

Now, I'm using this model method from my controller

```
        function actionYourController()
        {
            $model=new MyModel();        
            $isParamExist=isset($_GET['ulip']);
            $customer_basics_id=CustomerBasics::getCustomerBasicsId(Yii::app()->session['user_id']);        
            $activeData=$model->yourModelMethod($isParamExist,$customer_basics_id);
            $this->render('myView',array('activeData'=>$activeData));
        }
```

I hope, it will definitely solve your problem.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not really sure this will really take care of your problem. But at least it adheres to safe coding practices:

```
public function search()
{    
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria;

    $criteria->compare('user_details_id', $this->user_details_id);
    $criteria->compare('user_type_id', $this->user_type_id);
    $criteria->compare('user_address_id', $this->user_address_id);
    $criteria->compare('is_active', $this->is_active);
    $criteria->compare('create_dttm', $this->create_dttm, true);
    $criteria->compare('update_dttm', $this->update_dttm, true);

    $criteria->compare('customer_basics_id', CustomerBasics::getCustomerBasicsId(Yii::app()->session['user_id']));

    if(isset($_GET['ulip']))
        $criteria->addCondition('user_city_id IS NULL');
    else
        $criteria->addCondition('user_city_id IS NOT NULL');

    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria' => $criteria,
        'pagination' => array(
            'pageSize' => 10,
        ),
    ));
}
```

Comment: can you please elaborate as to how your version is safer than the OP's

Comment: Simple: No string concatenation to build query parts and safer parameter binding. There is no longer a bogus `compare()` for the `customer_basics_id` and `user_city_id`. I suspect latter one has been causing the troubles.

Comment: I just got put in my place

Answer (score 0):

I've just created table in MySQL, model, crud, based on your fields and your search criteria, plus some test data. In my tests all works, both conditions generate some results.

If your need more information about my tests don't hesitate to ask. I suppose, error is connected with input data, hence I suggest to turn on debug mode, add log component to your config and after that look on sql queries that's yii generate.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `$criteria->addCondition("user_city_id <> '' ");` solve the probleme because IS NOT NULL interpreted as true and NULL as false.